# How to insert on top in sqlite? LIMIT does not work

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, sql-insert

Is there a INSERT TOP(...) statement in SQLite?
Following problem:

1. I create a table with 5 columns
2. I INSERT 4 of the 5 columns from a different table
3. Now I want to INSERT the 5th column from a third table

With the code I wrote the INSERT for column 5 adds new rows and values do not fill up the column from the top.

```
co.execute('''CREATE TABLE newtable1 (column1 text, column2 int, column3 int, column4 text,column5 text)''')
co.execute('''INSERT INTO newtable1 (column1, column2, column3, column4) SELECT column1a, column2a, column3a, column4a  FROM db1''')
c.commit()


co.execute('''INSERT INTO newtable1 (column5) SELECT newColumn FROM db2''')
c.commit()
```

I am looking for something like

```
co.execute('''INSERT INTO newtable1 (column5) SELECT TOP (9999) newColumn FROM db2''')
```

I tried LIMIT, but it creates again 9999 extra rows.

```
co.execute('''INSERT INTO newtable1 (column5) SELECT  newColumn FROM db2 LIMIT 9999''')
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UPDATE on the created rows

UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];

or INSERT from the start

```
INSERT INTO newtable1 (column1 , column2, column3, column4, column5) SELECT column1a, column2a, column3a, column4a , newColumn  FROM db1, db2
```

Comment: I tried out this:

UPDATE newtable1 SET column5 = (SELECT newColumn FROM db2 ) WHERE column5 IS NULL

it does fill up all rows, but only with the first entry of newColumn. I need first value of newColumn in row1 and the second value of newColumn in row2...

Comment: INSERT INTO newtable1 (column1 , column2, column3, column4, column5) SELECT column1a, column2a, column3a, column4a , newColumn  FROM db1, db2